# Does bookmarking a question increase the reputation of the questioner?

Tags: support, reputation, bookmarks

If we bookmark a question, does the reputation of the questioner increase?

Answer (score 3):

No, starring or bookmarking a post does not give the OP reputation.

Only by upvoting the question can you influence the OP reputation, nothing else.